# flutter requires SDK version, but version is correctly installed

Tags: flutter, dart, fvm

```
$fvm flutter run 
Running "flutter pub get" in flutterweb...                      
The current Dart SDK version is 2.13.4.

Because flutterweb requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
```

I have this error.

Hoever --version is 2.14.2

```
$ dart --version
Dart SDK version: 2.14.2 (stable) (Wed Sep 15 12:32:06 2021 +0200) on "macos_x64"
```

in pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"
```

Where should I check??

Comment: Try : sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it this way: Open the `cmd` as Administrator, and run:

```
flutter upgrade
```

This works for me.

[image: Code at cmd]

Comment: It works for me too thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Which Flutter version are you using? 2.5?

Because different flutter versions require different dart versions. You should try `flutter upgrade` and if that doesn't fix it, try `flutter channel stable`.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I thought I have to upgrade dart itself, but flutter can upgrade dart as you told.